# Как получить _id созданного документа в MongoObservable?

Tags: mongodb, angular2, meteor

Возможно, некорректно задан вопрос, но все-таки.

Я создаю коллекцию таким образом:

```
export const BookCollection = new MongoObservable.Collection<Book>('books');
```

Но, как я понял, у метода `BookCollection.insert` нету второго аргумента.

Как я могу получить `_id`?

Пробовал `BookCollection.insert(...).then(...)`, но там ничего похожего на `id` вообще и близко нету.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как это rx попробуйте так:

```
BookCollection.insert(book)
        .toPromise()
        .then(function(res, err) {
            console.log(res, err);
        });
```

Comment: Как по маслу. res как раз и есть ид созданного документа.